# Why can't this python code not be executed?

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-python

As soon as I run this python code that includes some mysql, all I get are the three greater or less signs(>>>). Any help would be much appreciated!
My code consists of trying to obtain temperatures through a ds18b20 connected to my raspberry pi 3 and sending that data into a mysql database that I have created.

Here is the python/mysql code :

```
import os
import glob
import time
import MySQLdb
import datetime

i = datetime.datetime.now()

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "test", db = "temp_pi")
cur = db.cursor()

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c
    while True:
          print ("recording data into database(period = 5s.)....press ctrl+Z to stop!")

          valT = str(read_temp())

          year = str(i.year)
          month = str(i.month)
          day = str(i.day)
          date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year

          hour = str(i.hour)
          minute = str(i.minute)
          second = str(i.second)
          timestr = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second

          try:
             cur.execute("""INSERT INTO TAB_CLASSROOM(temp_c,T_Date,T_Time) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)""",(valT,date,time))
             db.commit()
          except:
             db.rollback()

          time.sleep(10)

    cur.close()  
    db.close()
```

Comment: when you run it like this `python something.py` from the command line?

Comment: This is rather long code you are expecting people to read. You should a) include more information about *how* you are running the code, including your OS, and b) cut down the code as much as possible which still demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @aws_apprentice when I run it in the python module.

Comment: "@aws_apprentice when I run it in the python module." - please be more specific, what does that mean? Python is an executable program. It happens to run code in modules.

Comment: @mdurant well I am new sorry about that. My code connects to mysql db(line 9-10), reads the temperature through my sensor that I specified in the description (12-35), then sends them through to the table(51-55) and closes the connection at last.

Comment: The question was, how are you running your code. It's OK if you are pressing a button in some code editor, but please tell everyone.

Comment: @mdurant I am running my code through the Thonny Python IDE. I am also executing this through my raspberry pi.

Comment: I figured out my issue! I had to take out the `While True` indent! I also had to define db and cur. @mdurant

Answer (score 0):

You've never run anything inside that code. The bulk of your code is inside `read_temp()` and it isn't called anywhere in it. The `>>>` means the program has ended and it's entered interpreter mode. Add some code after it for it to work the way you want it to.

Comment: it is called if you read the cur.execute line at the end. I define VaLT saying that it is read_temp(). That function is to insert the obtained temperature into my mysql table.

Comment: You haven't called `read_temp()`... Even if `cur.execute` is inside it, it won't run until the function around it runs.

Comment: I am unsure how else I would be able to call `read_temp()` @GeeTransit

Comment: Call it at the end. Very end, not indented. Then it should be fine.

Comment: If I add it at the very bottom of the code with no indent, I get `invalid syntax`. @GeeTransit I added `read_temp()` at the very bottom and I am getting the new error I just showed you.

Comment: I figured out my issue! I had to take out the `While True` indent! I also had to define db and cur. @GeeTransit

Answer (score 0):

You are not, in fact running anything. Assuming you do

```
python myscript.py
```

python will load the file and run it - which means execute the code line-by-line. You will find that the first few lines outside of functions are simply executed. Then you define some functions, but never call them.

You should probably add

```
read_temp()
```

at the end of the script.

Comment: he has no `if __name__ == "__main__"` either

Comment: @mdurant I did add that line at the end of the script and I still am getting nothing in response of the code execution.

Comment: I notice that read_temp() calls read_temp again at `valT = str(read_temp())` - so you just recurse and never get to the database insert.

Comment: @mdurant ok. How exactly would I be able to get to the database insert? Thank you for your help, very much appreciated!

Comment: ...don't call read_temp() from within read_temp()? We don't actually know what you are trying to achieve here, so hard to say.

Comment: @mdurant I am trying to obtain the temperature data and trying to be able to send that same data into a table including the data and the time it was taken. The temperature that I am trying to get through would be = read_temp(). So that is why I thought I should call it to send it into the database but I guess it is not the case.